# No sound - Ubuntu Mate 21.04 + Chromebook

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, ubuntu-mate, chromebook

When I open sound settings, No profile options are listed for "Built-in audio" except for "Off".

Machine is a Acer Chromebook Spin 713 with MrChromeBox coreboot firmware and Ubuntu MATE 21.04 installed (however, issue also exists with Lubuntu 20.04.3). Laptop has built-in speakers and a 3.5mm audio jack, but does not recognize any playback audio devices except HDMI.

Sound Device:
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP cAVS
DeviceName: Multimedia audio controller
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP cAVS
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 64, IRQ 148
Memory at 9fa14000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
Memory at 9f900000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
Capabilities: 
Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci

alsa-info output:
http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=7d8c2e0f06a902f817c71fdf4aae1f16e7b21227

Note: I have made one modification to /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf, adding the following line:
"options snd-hda-intel dmic-detect=0"
Before this, the laptop's sound card was not being recognized at all.

alsa-info output from before:
http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=3c348ee95fa38bceb3f25e38e4de431766f808c8

Comment: What error messages when running `sudo dmesg | grep audio` command?

Comment: I have the exact same issue, but I have an Samsung Galaxy Chromebook Go 14" (Jasper Lake intel chip) that I loaded with MrChromebox RW_LEGACY firmware, and I now run Ubuntu 22.04.

Audio only works over HDMI, not 3.5mm jack nor internal speakers (the device is listed as "Dummy Driver" in the sound settings).

`sudo dmesg | grep audio` lists: ```[    3.653584] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])```, so the driver appears to be working fine.

Comment: Try this. https://askubuntu.com/a/1469281/124466