# How to fix no audio on Asus c302c runing a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04 via MrChromeBox

Tags: sound, asus, chromebook

An intial search showed two posts recommending a kernel rebuild when using the older Ubuntu 20.04 and another post elsewhere that I can't find anymore suggesting this was fixed with the new Ubuntu 22.04:
https://devendor.github.io/c302ca/
[Getting sound to work on Asus C302C (Chromebook)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1448750/getting-sound-to-work-on-asus-c302c-chromebook)
**Any recommendations on an audio fix for an ASUS C302C Chromebook running a clean install of Ubuntu 22.04 via MrChromeBox UEFI?**

Answer (score 1):

I have working sound in ubuntu 23.04 with avs driver using https://github.com/eupnea-linux/audio-scripts and with kernel upgraded to 6.3.5. Default 23.04 kernel (6.2.0)  didn't work for me.

Note: The repository got shifted to https://github.com/WeirdTreeThing/chromebook-linux-audio

Comment: Does the microphone work?

Comment: After a bit of fiddling yes it does work.

Comment: Can you add more details of how you tweaked, so that future users can use it as well?

Comment: Actually just selecting the correct device in microphone settings works for me. Also the audio scripts seem to have moved to https://github.com/WeirdTreeThing/chromebook-linux-audio